# How to extract timestamp from MongoDB object

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my php app, I do a db query that returns a bunch of documents from mongodb.  As i'm looping through each document, i'm trying to extract the timestamp and display it as a Y-M-d h:i:s format.  But I'm not even sure at this point how to extract it.

I'm testing with this code:

```
    var_dump($value->playbook_run_date);
```

That outputs/ returns this:

```
object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#9 (1) {
  ["milliseconds"]=>
  string(13) "1486277081000"
}
```

I've tried to change the code to look like this:

```
  var_dump($value->playbook_run_date['milliseconds']);
```

But that returns the error:

> Cannot use object of type MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime as array

I've been googling around for that error and have tried a few examples including:

```
var_dump($value->playbook_run_date->{'milliseconds'});
var_dump($value->playbook_run_date->1->{'milliseconds'});
var_dump($value->playbook_run_date[1]->{'milliseconds'});
```

But I can't seem to figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.todatetime.php

Code looks like this:

```
$temp = $value->playbook_run_date->toDateTime();
echo ("<td>".$temp->format('r') ."</td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Object properties with numerical names need to be referenced as a string surrounded by curly braces:

```
 var_dump($value->playbook_run_date->{'1'}['milliseconds']); // If 'milliseconds is an array key
 var_dump($value->playbook_run_date->{'1'}->milliseconds); // If milliseconds is an object property
```

Comment: i tried both examples and they return "Undefined property" error messages

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$value->playbook_run_date->__toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($value->playbook_run_date);
```

> That outputs/ returns this:

```
object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#9 (1) {
                                         ["milliseconds"]=>
                                         string(13) "1486277081000"
                                       }
```

You can try this:

```
//--first deserialize the MonogoDB date object 
$playbook_run_date_unix_timestamp = $value->playbook_run_date->jsonSerialize()['$milliseconds'];
                                 
//--then you can work with the results any how you want
$playbook_run_date_datetime_format = date("Y-M-d h:i:s", ($playbook_run_date_unix_timestamp/1000) );
```